# Tax impact of receiving a bank transfer and making a purchase for a friend?

Tags: taxes, australia, cryptocurrency

I have a permanent residency in Australia, and I have a bank account there. A friend asked me if he can transfer money to my account and then I send it to a bitcoin exchange that he wants to work with. He wants to do it this way because he lives in a country that is not recognized by the exchange. My question is, what are the potential tax impacts of doing this for him?

(Note: my focus is not on the safety or other implications of performing this transaction, only the legal / tax impacts)

Comment: Is this a really good friend who you trust with your life? Because having someone send you money to send on somewhere else is a classic scam.

Comment: Your bitcoin exchange account or theirs?  Because its much riskier if its theirs.  If its yours there is much less risk.   But if its yours the tax liability will potentially hit you.

Comment: He is an old friend and I know him well, so no it’s not a scam. And I want to send the money to his account on the exchange not mine.. will I be liable for taxation?

Comment: Sounds like friendship problems waiting to happen. My advice - don't become a financial intermediary for your friend, regardless of how god a friend he is. What happens if the next day, value of bitcoin gets cut in half (or doubles)? Who gets the loss / profit? See related answer here: https://money.stackexchange.com/a/84861/44232

Comment: Ok thanks for the responses and I appreciate your concerns but my focus is on the taxation laws in Australia if anyone can help?

Comment: @user1221612 I've edited to be more in-line with what you're asking about, hopefully this suits your intent.

Comment: If any of this money is implicated in any crime, you are boned.

Comment: Is there a reason he can't fund his account on the exchange directly? Or use an exchange in his native currency?

Comment: Yes, he is living in a country that doesn’t support both options..

Comment: The question is old but one good answer to this friend is: Don't waste time with bitcoin or gambling. This will be an advice from real friend.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think there is really any tax implication from your viewpoint.  You’re simply acting as his agent, or potentially a constructive or implied trustee.

If you were to make profit on the transaction then you’d have to declare that profit as income.

If you’re going to keep the bitcoin in your name then you’re effectively holding the bitcoin in trust where he is the beneficiary.

Imagine the situation where an office colleague gives you a fiver for you to get him a cup of coffee - you’re acting as his agent.

If you wanted to get into the details, the areas of law are (1) agency and (2) trust law.

If you or your friend wanted an arrangement that was legally enforceable (you wanted to reserve the right to sue each other) then you might want to get a lawyer to draft an agreement but that is probably overkill if they are a friend that you trust.

These concepts of trust and agency tend to apply only in “Common Law” jurisdictions based on English law (Australia, Canada, New Zealand, US, etc.)

Comment: Thanks, this is what makes sense to me but is this a legal fact or personal opinion?

Comment: I have updated my answer.  It is a well known legal principle.