# Picking up money for someone else on Moneygram ? Is it safe?

Tags: iban

A close friend of mine asked me if I could pick up money for him using my ID from money gram since he had already exceeded the receiving limit this month. The amount was 500 euros. I just wanted to know if it was safe to do this.

Comment: You know there's a limit. You are offering to help break that limit. Whoever put that limit in place won't be happy with you breaking that limit. Chances are that the limit is mandated by law, meaning that you are thinking about breaking the law. This is the sort of question that answers itself.

Answer (score 6):

**Don't pick up the money.** It doesn't matter how much it's for, but the general rule is: if it feels like you shouldn't be doing it... then you shouldn't.

Whilst it might not be a scam, it's likely very illegal. Refer to [this post](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/94785/a-friend-asks-me-all-the-time-to-pick-up-money-for-her-western-union-moneygram) for more information - especially Ben Miller's post, and 0xfee1dead's comment underneath.

Honestly, I know friends are important... but you're being asked to unknowingly do something, like launder money. You could get in to serious trouble for this, and no amount of naivety will save you.

Comment: "no amount of naivety will save you" .... well not anymore, now that you told him....