# A person wants to deposit 2.1 million into my account

Tags: australia, scams

A man wants me to transfer 2.1 million into my account and then have me purchase properties with the money. Am I being scammed? He has given his banking info, Password, and routing information.

Comment: He has given you *somebody's* banking info, password, and routing information.

Comment: I doubt even that.... I assume he made a website that looks like a banking website and gave out an account number and password :p

Comment: The easiest way to detect a scam: Ask what is in it for them and why they need you. In this case are you a bank or a realtor who normally does this type of transaction? if not why in the world would they trust you with so much money when there are lots of more traditional ways to buy real estate. A: He is scamming you, or using you as an accomplice in a crime so you can take the heat.

Comment: Once again, this response fits: https://money.stackexchange.com/a/71013/17718

Answer (score 13):

Yes, this is scam. Absolutely and 100%.

The details of the scam may vary, but are largely irrelevant as far as the correct course of action goes - which is to cut all communications with this person, and stay away.

As a side note, no one ever needs to know your banking password, and you'd never need to know theirs.